# AWK if clause to combine fields

Tags: awk

I have a tab delimited file with >10,000 rows, and a variable number of columns per row (33-35).

For rows with 34 columns, I would like to collapse columns 3-4 into one:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4   ...   col34
index1  tool     kit    math         new
```

to -->

```
col1   col2    col3   ...   col33
index1 tool    kit;math     new
```

Likewise, for 35 columns, I would like to collapse columns 3-5 into one. My hunch is that there might be a way to utilize AWK and NF to accomplish this. Any tips or help?

Comment: Let's forget about 35 columns for now and make a simple example with fewer columns showing exactly what the input and desired output look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In awk:

```
NF>5 {                                         # if more than 5 (33) fields
    for(i=(NF-5)-1; i>=0; i--)                 # execute next for once or twice
        for(j=3+i; j<=NF; j++)                 
            $j=( j<4+i ? $j ";" : "" ) $(j+1)  # catenate once or twice on i
    NF=5 
} $1=$1                                        # is this a problem?
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' -f program.awk karakfa\'s.txt
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1       2       3;4     5       6
1       2       3       4       5
1       2       3;4;5   6       7
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this shorter by using a for loop to loop through the fields given your two or three conditions, but long-hand (and more understandable for an awk newbie) is:

```
awk 'NF==35{print $1,$2,$3$4$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35} NF==34{print $1,$2,$3$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34} NF==33{$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33}' yourfile.txt
```

That's a mouthful, but it's just printing out different combinations of your fields based on the number of fields present in the record.

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful and makes sense. In this format would I have to pre-specify all possibilities? For example, would this exclude rows where NF < 33? I would only like to specifically change rows with NF == 34 and NF == 35 and keep all else as is.

Comment: This would exclude records that weren't 33, 34, or 35 fields long. You could change that last condition to `NF<=33` or `NF!=34 && NF!=35` or `NF<34 || NF>35` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

here is another `awk` with more flexibility.  I used 5-7 columns instead.

```
$ cat file
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1       2       3       4       5       6
1       2       3       4       5
1       2       3       4       5       6       7

$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{print; next} 
                    NF>5{$3=$3 $4; t=1} 
                    NF>6{$3=$3 $5; t=2} 
                       t{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) $i=$(i+t);
                         NF=NF-t; t=0}1' file

col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1       2       34      5       6
1       2       3       4       5
1       2       345     6       7
```

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) implementation of [awk paradigm](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-000264BC) in some [270 lines of TXR Lisp](http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/share/txr/stdlib/awk.tl):

Warm-up: basic column coalescing all across the file:

```
$ txr -e '(awk ((>= nf 4) (set [f 2..4] (list `@[f 2];@[f 3]`)))
               (t))'
1
1
1 2
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3;4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3;4 5
```

The fields are a list `f`, rather than a special syntactic gadget involving dollar signs, so they are susceptible to a slice assignment: `(set [target-sequence n..m] source-sequence)` replaces the `n..m` slice (from `n` to `m`, exclusive of `m`) of `target-sequence` with `source-sequence`. Indexing is from zero, so to replace the third and fourth fields, we denote the slice `2..4`: i.e. index 2 and 3, not including 4.

The `(t)` is a condition-action clause with no conditions, analogous to Awk's `1`: it triggers the implicit `(prn)` form which prints `rec` (the equivalent of `$0`); `t` is a self-evaluating symbol which canonically denotes a Boolean true, though any value other than `nil` is true. When `f` is manipulated in certain ways, such as by the above slice assignment, `rec` is automatically re-constituted from the fields by inserting `ofs` between them, just like field twiddling in Awk Classic reconstitutes `$0`.

Now, how about handling the first row as headings to be printed and then ignored:

```
$ txr -e '(awk ((= nr 1) (prn) (next))
               ((>= nf 4) (set [f 2..4] (list `@[f 2];@[f 3]`)))
               (t))'
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 3 3;4 5
```

Next, we have a requirement about the changing range for 34 versus 35. How about we use the condition "34 or more columns". The shifting range can be handled by changing the expression:

```
[f 2..4]
```

to

```
[f (if (> nf 34) 2..5 2..4))]
```

but we can do it in a unified way if we bind the conditionally range to a variable and then use it in several places. We only have to test the condition once. The result is:

```
$ txr -e '(awk ((= nr 1) (prn) (next))
               ((>= nf 4) (let ((r (if (> nf 34) 2..5 2..4)))
                            (set [f r] (list `@{[f r] ";"}`))))
               (t))'
col1 col2 ...
col1 col2 ...
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y
1 2 3;4;5 6 7 8 9 0 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X
1 2 3;4 5 6 7 8 9 0 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X
```

Inside a backtick-delimited quasi-string-literal, the syntax `@{[seq range] string}` will interpolate a slice of a sequence, using string as the separator. We simply interpolate the range `r`, which is the same range that we are deleting and replacing with the resulting string; we switch `r` conditionally on whether we have more than 34 columns, so the test is in just once place, and `r` used in two places.

Comment: Sincerely appreciate the explanation and help!!